# Salesforce remote action call error

Tags: salesforce

I am calling one apex remote action which is throwing below error in some cases.. This is working fine on lower env. but in Production it is breaking. I am suspecting this is not from the UI rather from the apex controller side.

Please see below error details. Below error details I received from apex controller side.

```
[
    {
      "statusCode":500,
      "type":"exception",
      "ref":false,
      "action":"Unknown",
      "method":"Unknown",
      "message":"Content type 'null' not supported for Visualforce remoting request.  Expected 'application/json'.",
      "where":"",
      "data":"",
      "vfTx":true,
      "vfDbg":true
     }
]
```

**Ajax header screenshot:**

[image]

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your remote action is working in Sandbox but not Production.  Here are the things I would check

1. Check that you deployed both your Visualforce page and Controller.
2. Check the security on the Visualforce page to ensure the profile has access
3. Check the security on the Apex Class to ensure the profile has access
4. Check the Object and Field Level Security for the user's profile for the fields used in the remote action
5. Add a console.log to the line before the remote action is called that logs the parameters passed into the remote action
6. Add a console log to the function within the remote action that handles the callback that logs the response
7. Add a System.Debug to the first line of the remote action that logs the input parameters

If the first 4 items don't fix the issue, the last 3 will help further identify it.

Comment: Hi Matt.... asked salesforce team to validate point 1 o 4, everything seems fine. 5 to 7 also do not seem any issue, data is going properly. Remote calls failing when data is more......so when i click on link on left panel which has less data the remote calls are successful but when data is large the calls are getting canceled.